# Communication between file and container

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache-flex

I have a `flex` program that opens a `html`  file in a custom component (`mxml`). This `html` file may contain `audio`, `video` or other type of media files (one predefined file extension per media). I need to know that if these files opened/clicked/started on that `html` file. The first thing came to my mind is using `php` but I do not have an idea about the script/language.

So what are the possible solutions to achieve such communication? Is `php` okay or can `JavaScript` handle?

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: First answer indicated I was not clear enough. So the solution I am looking for can be able to directly tell the container that media is opened (like trigger).

Edit #2: I am putting an image to illustrate the structure and problem. At this point I wonder if `JavaScript` can pass a value to the `flex` application. Not sure to handle how to talk back to "container" method. If the method have the information which one is clicked and not, I can change the displaying status of these media files as opened/viewed.

[image: basic scheme]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of approaches to this. One way would be to use JavaScript. Simply by using an onclick event on the html tag.

Say you have this snippet of HTML:

```
<mxml class="video" type="video">..Video stuff..</mxml>
<mxml class="video" type="video">..Video stuff..</mxml>
<mxml class="video" type="video">..Video stuff..</mxml>
<mxml class="video" type="video">..Video stuff..</mxml>
```

A simple bit of JavaScript could be:

```
function initElement() {
    // get all the elemts into an array
    var vids = document.getElementsByClassName('video');

    for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
        vids[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Define what the vid should do when clicked
            // you can use the 'this' keyword to refer to the current vid

            console.log(this);

        });
    };
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName for more information

Comment: I am assuming `doStuff` method tells me that video is clicked. So I have noticed I need to edit my question. Because I am looking for programmatical way instead of `alert`. What I mean is the `mxml` component should have known that that was clicked.

Comment: I updated the snippet a bit. This way you can get all the elements with the class video. Get those in an array and bind an onClick event to each one.